# Android, Multiple dex files define

Tags: android, jar

I don't know why I'm getting this error. the jar that causes it is added ONLY ONCE to a library which in turns is added to the project. I've gone through almost every Stack overflow question. if its added ONCE, how can it be seen more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you get this error due to some file inside jar that has some common name and conflicting with another in some other jar? INFO.txt, for example.
Also, have you checked the dependencies of other libraries, if you have any?

Comment: Yes, I checked the dependencies.